# Solving 4- bar Mechanism simultaneous equations

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Using Complex number analysis on a [4- bar mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbL5.png)
I arrive with two simultaneous equations that I do not know how to solve.

Separating real and Imaginary parts

$$ r3cos(\theta_3)-r4cos(\theta_4) = r1-r2cos(\theta_2) $$
$$ r3sin(\theta_3)-r4sin(\theta_4) = -r2sin(\theta_2)
    $$

I am to assume all lengths (r1, r2, r3, r4) & $\theta_2 $ are known.

Therefore, I need to solve for $\theta_3$ &  $\theta_4$

any input?

Comment: I made a mistake with both second terms needing to be negative. (i believe)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly simpler is to use the Cosine and Sine Rules in triangles ABC and ACO :

$$AC^2=r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta_2$$
$$AC\sin\angle ACO=r_2\sin\theta_2$$
$$r_3^2=AC^2+r_4^2-2ACr_4\cos\angle ACB$$
$$r_4^2=r_3^3+AC^2-2ACr_3\cos\angle CAB$$
$$\theta_3=\angle CAB - \angle ACO$$
$$\theta_4=180^{\circ}-\angle ACO-\angle ACB$$

Answer (score 0):

Square both equations and add them.  The left side will be $-2r3r4\sin(\theta_3)\sin(\theta_4)\cos(\theta_3)\cos(\theta_4)$ plus some constants.  Take the constants to the other side and use the double angle formula on the left.  You get $\sin (2\theta_3)\sin(2\theta_4)$.  Also subtract the squared equations and you can use the cosine double angle formula.

Comment: I made a mistake: it's supposed to be a negative second term in both equations (have corrected the post to reflect this). Does that change your method to solve?

Comment: Not at all.  If you follow through, the point is that you get $\sin^2+\cos^2$ when you square and add and the middle terms subtract out when you square and subtract.  Changing the sign does not change this.

Comment: So square both equations and add the two equations?

Comment: Yes, that is my first sentence.

Comment: After squaring and adding two equations, I arrive at:
$$3^2−234[(_3)(_4)−(_3)(_4)]+4^2=1^2+2^2−212(_2)+2(_2)$$
Opting to use Cos Addition identity on middle term (in [ ]) :
$$(_3+_4))$$
then:
$$(_3+_4))=$$

Comment: Which you can take the arccos of.  When you square and subtract you can get expressions in $\theta_3+\theta_4$ and $\theta_3-\theta_4$.  I think that gets you home, but it will be messy

Comment: Mr. Millikan, 
I thank you very much.